# Can this Event Calendar Extension be added to CiviCRM core?

Tags: civievent, webform-civicrm, core

Many of us look for calendar extensions with color coding.  This extension v1.1 was made in 2013 for CiviCRM 4.4, but I would like to know can it become part of CiviCRM core?

Event Calendar: https://civicrm.org/extensions/event-calendar-extension

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code quality of core is generally higher then that of the extensions. So if you can help funding it, it might improve your chances.

On the other hand, discussions lately are going in the direction to move more functionality from core to extensions then the other way around, although exceptions likely will occur.